# Mock $root with vue-test-utils and JEST

Tags: jestjs, vue-test-utils

My component has the following computed code:

```
textButton() {
    const key = this.$root.feature.name === //...
    // ...
},
```

Right now I'm trying desperately to mock "root" in my test, but I just don't know how. Any tips?

Answer (score 5):

Vue test utils provides you with the ability to inject mocks when you mount (or shallow mount) your component.

```js
const $root = 'some test value or jasmine spy'

let wrapper = shallow(ComponentToTest, {
  mocks: { $root }
})
```

That should then be easily testable. Hope that helps

Comment: It seems that since a recent release, mocks don't handle $root anymore, more here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/481#issuecomment-423716430 (see @awho answer)

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to accomplish this with `vue-test-utils`.

One way, as mentioned above, is using the `mocks` mounting option.

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo, {
  mocks: {
    $root: { 
      feature: { 
        name: "Some Val" 
      }
    }
  }
})
```

But in your case, you probably want to use the computed mouting option, which is a bit cleaner than a deep object in `mocks`.

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Foo, {
  computed: {
    textButton: () => "Some Value"
  }
})
```

Hopefully this helps!

If you are interested I am compiling a collection of simple guides on how to test Vue components [here](https://github.com/lmiller1990/vue-testing-handbook). It's under development, but feel free to ask make an issue if you need help with other related things to testing Vue components.

Answer (score 4):

Solution from https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/481#issuecomment-423716430:

You can set $root on the vm directly:

```
wrapper.vm.$root = { loading: true }
wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate()
```

Or you can pass in a parent component with the parentComponent mounting option. In VTU, the paren will be the $root:

```
const Parent = {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: "asdas"
    }
  }
}
const wrapper = shallowMount(TestComponent, {
  parentComponent: Parent
})
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use a Vue Plugin inside the test to inject the mock data into `localVue` so that your components can access it.

```
import {createLocalVue, shallow} from '@vue/test-utils';

const localVue = createLocalVue();

localVue.use((Vue) => {
  Vue.prototype.feature = {
    name: 'Fake news!'
  };
});

let wrapper = shallow(Component, {
  localVue
});
```

---

I had the same issues a while ago and I came to the conclusion that accessing `this.$root` may be a sign that you have to further improve the way you communicate with components. Consider using the plugin structure to define globally available properties and methods *not only inside the test* for example. Mixins might be helpful as well.

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mixins

Answer (score 0):

For people having the same problem in Vue 3 and [Vue Test Utils v2](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils):

I recommend wrapping `$root` accesses with component computed variables. So, replace this:

```
methods: {
    textButton() {
        const key = this.$root.feature.name === //...
        // ...
    },
}
```

with this:

```
computed: {
    feature() {
        return this.$root.feature;
    }
},
methods: {
    textButton() {
        const key = this.feature.name === //...
        // ...
    },
}
```

And then, in test implementation, mock this computed variable **before** mounting:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import MyComponent from '<path here>';

MyComponent.computed.feature = jest.fn(() => { name: 'random feature name' });
const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent);

...
```

This way you won't need to mock `$root` anymore.